# How is the conversion rate calculated in football?

Tags: football, statistics

I want to know how the conversion rate is calculated in the Premier League for example. I tried to make a report like shots/goals but it seems it's not the correct one. Any suggestions?

I'm looking for the method to calculate the conversion rate of shots. Something like what is showed in [this link](https://www.whoscored.com/Graphics/5844/Show/Diego-Costa-2014-15-vs-2015-16). It says that Diego Costa has an approximately 26% conversion rate.

I tried to divide shots on goal with goals scored but it's seems I'm not doing it the right way.

Answer (score 4):

Using your example it looks as thought the definition is simply:

**Conversion Rate  = Goals scored / Total shots**

From the information that in 2014/2015 Diego Costa had 2.9 Shots per game in 26 games, we know that he had a total of 75 or 76 shots over the season (both 75/26 and 76/26 round to 2.9 when 1 decimal place is used). He scored 20 goals, and using the value of 76 shots the conversion rate is 20/76 = 26.3%

[This irish sports site](http://www.sportsjoe.ie/football/stats-jonathan-walters-has-the-best-shot-conversion-rate-in-the-premier-league-this-season/19880) uses the definition **percentage shots scored** for conversion rate, which supports the above definition.